# Cannot implicity convert type 'object ' to system.collection.arraylist

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code I have a method it throws error while executing

> " Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to
>   'System.Collections.ArrayList'"

Please help me to do this.

```
private string strGetIndentString()
{
        ArrayList nArr = new ArrayList();
        System.Text.StringBuilder strInfo = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        if (Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] != null)
            nArr = Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];//throws error

        for (int i = 0; i < nArr.Count; i++)
             strInfo.Append(nArr[i].ToString() + ",");

        return strInfo.ToString().TrimEnd(",".ToCharArray());            
}
```

Comment: `Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"]` returns `object` but `nArr` is an  `ArrayList`. What are you try to do exactly? Are you try to append it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this where you are getting value form session

```
nArr=(ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The [array accessor from `Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dhkksh8(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an `object`, not an `ArrayList`, so you have to cast it:

```
nArr = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
```

Or (this one makes `nArr` `null` if the variable isn't an `ArrayList`:

```
nArr = Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] as ArrayList;
```

I strongly suggest to use the generic [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which is much safer since it is typed.

Comment: is it good to keep on Session? or better with sessionStorage?

Comment: @brykneval: What `sessionStorage`?

Comment: HTML sessionStorage if the the list gets high

Comment: @brykneval: I don't know how that is related to the question.

Comment: I mean to say, if its good to set those values to sessionStorage or Session?

Comment: @brykneval: They are to totally difference mechanisms for totally different purposes. You can't compare them. A server side security key can be safed in the `Session`, but I would never save it in `sessionStorage`.

Comment: @bry was the explanation sufficient?

Comment: bit of yes and no, in his case its just list of items so is there that need of security than flexibility that you can get from having stored in sessionStorage or even IndexDB

Answer (score 0):

As Error Says You Need to Again Cast Your Session Into `ArrayList`

```
private string strGetIndentString()
        {
            ArrayList nArr = new ArrayList();
            System.Text.StringBuilder strInfo = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            if (Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] != null)
                nArr =(ArrayList) Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];//throws error

            for (int i = 0; i < nArr.Count; i++)
                strInfo.Append(nArr[i].ToString() + ",");

            return strInfo.ToString().TrimEnd(",".ToCharArray());

        }
```